# updating the value of a parent variable from a directive's isolated scope using $scope.$parent do not update template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am updating the value of a parent variable from a directive's isolated scope using $scope.$parent.parentvariable.field = newfield.

When I console like console.log($scope.$parent.parentvariable.field), the field contains new values as seen in console. However, the template which should get updated (as it is bound with field) is not getting updated.

Using $apply() as $scope.$parent.$apply() throws $digest already in use error.

What is going wrong here?

Trying to do something like:

```
$scope.$parent.group_levers.levers.forEach(function (lv,indexLever) {
    if (lv.RFLeverId == lever.RFLeverId) {
        lv.description.leverValue.forEach(function (leverVal, indexLeverVal) {
            if (leverVal.RFLeverValueId == splashResponseRaw.levers[0].description.leverValue[0].RFLeverValueId) {
                $scope.$parent.group_levers.levers[indexLever].description.leverValue[indexLeverVal] = splashResponse;
                //$scope.$parent.$apply();
            }
        })
    }
})
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.$parent.$apply();
}, 10)
```

Comment: please add some code that you have done

Comment: updated with a code snippet

Comment: use setTimeout(function(){$scope.$apply();},0)

Answer (score 0):

try this. after a small fraction of milliseconds run apply.

```
$timeout(function(){
  scope.$apply();
},100)
```

Comment: timespan should be 0 or some value, say 100 or 50

Comment: and the scope used here will be directive's scope. i.e I should write inside directive controller as:
`$timeout(function(){
  scope.$apply();
},0)` after making my changes

Comment: you can keep it 100 but 0 also work because still it will be executed later on , ok i increase it to 100

Comment: scope should be parent scope.

Comment: So you mean to write it like:
`$timeout(function(){
  $scope.$parent.$apply();
},0)` correct me , if I am not getting you pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93589/discussion-between-saurabh-tiwari-and-nglover).

Comment: This didn't worked..still the template did'nt update